# Software rendering mode after Linux Mint update

Tags: x11, drivers, x-server, skylake

After I did some security updates, my video display became unstable (it was showing dust when some animations were to be displayed, as if the vidao cable was incorrectly plugged), I did not really know what to do so I uninstalled the latest package installed by the security update which was named "xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid". Then xserver stopped working...I followed some tutorial, installed some packages (as far as I remember "xserver-xorg-video-intel" and "cinnamon") and then, I could get my GUI/desktop back).

However, now the system complains that it runs in "software rendering mode" and it's true  the computer became slower, specially when rendering graphics.

So I believe there is a problem with my driver...?

I see `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` reports:

```
[     4.680] (EE) AIGLX error: Calling driver entry point failed
[     4.680] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

Here is the information I can supply right now:

```
> sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       ressources: irq:124 mémoire:de000000-deffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64)

> inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1600x1200@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes

> uname -a
Linux PCJEAN 4.4.0-109-generic #132~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 21:46:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Additionnaly:

```
> glxinfo
    ....
    name of display: :0
    libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 8086:1912, driver (null)
    i965_dri.so does not support the 0x1912 PCI ID.
    libGL error: failed to create dri screen
    libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
    ....
```

The "Gestionnaire de pilote" (probably "Driver manager" in English) is empty.

Could there be a driver mismatch (`sudo lshw -C video` reports i1915, `glxinfo` reports i965).

What operation could help xserver use my video card correctly?

---

Edit: [After reading this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/linux-mint-cinnamon-17-3-in-software-rendering-mode-issue-4175571760/), I switched to MATE. Message saying I was in software rendering mode is gone and GUI display seems faster, however, I still see `libGL error` when running glxgears and still see some refresh issues with some applications.